# Asymptotic probability: boys and girls in a line

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics

We have $n$ people: $\alpha n$ are boys and $(1-\alpha)n$ are girls. They are standing in a line in a random order. We pick up one boy also at random.

What can one say about the probability that there are more girls than boys before this randomly selected boy if $n\to \infty$?

Is it true that this probability is $O(1/n)$?

Edit:

Yes, i meant $\alpha>0.5$. What is the correct approach to find the coefficient before $1/n$?

Comment: No, because if $\alpha \lt \frac{1}{2}$ the probability goes to $1$.

Comment: You have a small issue that $\alpha n$ must be an integer, so $\alpha$ must be rational with $n$ a multiple of its lowest terms denominator.  Recasting the question it becomes $b m$ boys and $g m$ girls, with $b$, $g$ and $m$ positive integers (and $b>g$), what happens as $m \to \infty$?

Comment: Henry, i agree but i will leave current setup

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you forgot to specify $\alpha > 1/2$; otherwise the probability would tend to $1$, not to $0$. Yes, if $\alpha > 1/2$ the probability is $O(1/n)$, since the probability of each place in the line being chosen is the same and the probability of there being more girls than boys before a certain distance from the front doesn't depend on $n$ (or, to be more precise, depends on $n$ merely through the fact that knowing that there's one boy somewhere else slightly changes $\alpha$), and eventually falls of exponentially with the distance from the front, so the sum over the non-negligible contributions from the spots near the front eventually stops changing significantly, and from then on you're essentially just averaging over additional zeros, so the average will fall of with $1/n$.

Comment: And this reasoning shows that $n$ times the probability converges to the finite $1+\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}P(\mathrm{Bin}(n,\alpha)\lt\frac12 n)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $n$ is large enough, the fact that you pick a boy will not change the population appreciably.  I will use $a$ instead of $\alpha$ to save typing.  If you pick the first in line, the chance of more girls than boys is $0$.  If you pick the second, it is $(1-a)$.  The third $(1-a)^2$.  The fourth $(1-a)^3+3a(1-a)^2$.  If you pick the $k^{\text{th}}$, it is $$\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil \frac{k}{2} \rceil -1}{{k-1}\choose{i}}a^{k-i}(1-a)^i$$  You can keep adding these up until the $(1-a)^i$ term gets small enough to get the coefficient for $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Ross, i understand these probabilities but not how to get the coefficient before 1/n from them. Could you explain this idea?

Comment: Each of these accounts for one choice for who you picked,of which there are $n$ choices.  So you should add them up and divide by $n$.